# Report on opportunities that do not have a pricebook assigned

Tags: pricebook

We just introduced products and pricebooks into our org.

I am looking to update all historical data as well. I want to see, which opptys do not have a pricebook attached to them, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Formula Field on Opportunities by clicking on ⚙ > Setup > Object Manager > Opportunities > Fields & Relationships > New, choosing the Formula data type, then naming the field (I recommend "Has Price Book") with a Checkbox return type, then use the formula `Pricebook2Id <> NULL`, and then finishing up the wizard. After this brief setup (default values are fine). After this, you can add "Has Price Book equals false" to an Opportunity report to find all Opportunities that do not have an assigned Price Book.

Or, you can go with the slightly less accurate method, and just use `Has Products equals false` instead. If the Opportunity has a Product, it definitely has a Price Book, although this filter won't be able to differentiate between Opportunities that simply don't have any products, and those that don't have a Price Book assigned, but you avoid having to set up a custom formula field.